# Regarding CentOS 6.10 to CentOS 7 upgrade

Tags: centos7, centos6, vmware-vcenter, upgrade

I have servers in VMWARE, trying to upgrade the OS from CentOS 6.10 to CentOS 7, 
1) redhat upgrade tool installed but could not find any proper base url to download the package from online. 
2) Tried to upgrade via CentOS 7 iso, but it is failing due to dependency issues. The list is quite large and I am not sure why is it giving this error because I continued to keep this server updated with latest updates from its own repo and still I am getting these errors.

It would be great if any one can help me on this.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not recommended to upgrade across major OS versions. A clean install on a new host - especially when working with VMs already - is preferred.

Comment: Agreed with pmdba.

Comment: VMware is a company, a company that sells lots of products, just saying 'in VMWARE' tells us nothing and has no bearing on this question anyway - we expect more of question askers, please read our help pages.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to say VMware ESX. However, you would be more helpful if you link in the [corresponding help pages](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The Red Hat upgrade tool is for Red Hat Enterprise Linux and requires a subscription so that you can add the Red Hat repo and install the package from it. You are running 
CentOS so this isn't possible.

As others have stated, it isn't best practice to upgrade across major versions as things are likely to not work. This is why you are seeing the errors. The reliable method is to install RHEL 7 or RHEL 8 on another machine and then install the software and put the needed configurations in place. This way, you can test everything as you put it in place and make sure that everything is working. This is the best way if it's a production system.